# Spring Framework: how to accept array of objects as one of data params when receiving POST request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, http

When I send my request one of data params (newUsers) is always null.

No exception is thrown but server logs tell me that only projectId and groupName are not null amongst bean's fields. '$scope.projectTeam' is an array of objects, that's the difference.

**AngularJS part:**

```
$scope.saveChangesInProject = function (userId) {

    if ($scope.projectTeam != null) {
        // From the logs I know my scope.projectTeam contains all the chosen users
        $http({
            method: 'POST', 
            url: '/app/project/saveProject', 
            data: {
                projectId: $routeParams.projectId,
                newUsers: $scope.projectTeam,
                groupName: "qwerty123",
            }
        }); 
    }           
}
```

**Spring method declaration:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
ResponseEntity<Project> saveProject(@RequestBody (required = true) ProjectBean projectBean) throws HibernateValidationException;
```

**Java bean:**

```
@Component
public class ProjectBean {

    private Long id;
    private Long projectId;
    private String groupName;
    private List<User> newUsers;

// getters and setters etc
```

I tried to do this with FormData, but I got "Required request body content is missing". Also tried with Angular.toJson().

Comment: Have you tried with a hard coded array of objects to just verify that it works with the Backend?

Comment: Cannot see sth like `newUsers` in your spring code. Please clarify.

Comment: @Sim_on: it seems it doesn't accept hard coded array either. I think it should be a JSON when one of the fields is a json array

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt: it is a field in my Java bean. Added it to the question.

Comment: I think you don't want `ProjectBean` NOT to be annotated with `@Component`. This is used for Spring managed Beans (dependency injection).